# How to transfer tensorflow environment to root environment in anaconda navigator

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I installed tensorflow successfully using anaconda terminal.

Guide - https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows

But this guide create new environment called tensorflow therefore I want install this tensorflow in my root environment because it has 217 packagers and when I run a python program in tensorflow environment can't import root environment packagers. therefor I want to transfer or re-install tensorflow in root environment.

[Anaconda Navigator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0og9.png)

I opened anaconda terminal and `activate root`. Then I typed `pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow-gpu` like I did in tensorflow environment.

Then I get following error.

```
 Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 323, in clobber
    shutil.copyfile(srcfile, destfile)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\shutil.py", line 121, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\six.py'
You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 10.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

**How to install tensorfow in my root environment because I want use some of there 217 packagers also.**

Answer (score 0):

It seems this issue is related to opening the destination file with 'wb' permissions.

You might try running the Anaconda prompt with Administrator privileges. To do so:

- Right click `cmd.exe`
- Select `Run As Adminstrator`
- Navigate to the proper directory where you wish to run the command
- Run the command